# py3.7 TensorFlow The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

As above, I have a problem importing tensorflow.
Here is the output with the IDLE:

```
Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32     
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", l
ine 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", l
ine 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 1
27, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 2
42, in load_module
        return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Users\sungn_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 3
42, in load_dynamic
        return _load(spec)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

    See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

    for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
    above this error message when asking for help.
```

I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit, Python 3.7. Installed tensorflow 2.1.0 with pip install tensorflow.
Saw some GitHub issues and some Stack Overflow questions, but none of them fixed the issue.
Didn't install CUDA or something else. Is this effective with this?
What is wrong with this??

**EDIT** Sorry, installed Tensorflow with Anaconda (latest). Made an enviroment in it.

Answer (score 0):

**

> You Need To setup first Virtual Environment for Tensorflow

**

then

**pip install --upgrade tensorflow**

after install please Verify the install:

**python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"**

Comment: TensorFlow was already the latest version. The output after the second command was same as above.